# How to use artifact from google artifact registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have published my project .jar to artifact registry. I'm not sure how to refer to it, to use as a dependency in another project (with gradle). Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to this article, this feature is still in "alpha" and would require you to explicitly sign-up for access: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java

Answer (score 1):

As described in this [page](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication#gradle), you have to [register your project through this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf5q3CeDna_c27ifadF1KO17W3PrYO91w-UI-jjUdnvGS1cmQ/viewform?usp=sf_link) and then to configurer your Gradle repositories as [described](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication#repo)